# MySQL-python interface is not inserting data with MySQL server version 5.5.27

Tags: python

I am using MySQL-python interface 1.2.3 and MySQL server version 5.1.63.

Writing python script to create Table and insert data into the table. Its working Fine.

Now i am using  MySQL server version 5.5.27 and executing same script to create table and insert data. i am able to create Tables but unable to insert data into the Table.

I am not able to get where i am doing wrong.

Could anyone help me how to overcome from this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Update your MySQL db connector module

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-python-versions.html

Answer (score 0):

When i was using MySQL server version 5.1.63 at that time i was not using db_connection.commit() to save the data into database. But without using also i was able to save data into MySQL database.

Example:

```
  c = conn.cursor()

  # Create table
  c.execute('''CREATE TABLE stocks
         (date text, trans text, symbol text, qty real, price real)''')

  # Insert a row of data
  c.execute("INSERT INTO stocks VALUES ('2006-01-05','BUY','RHAT',100,35.14)")
```

After this execution data will update into database.

But with 5.5.27 MySQL server version we need to use db_connection.commit() to save the data into database.

Example:
     c = conn.cursor()

```
 # Create table
 c.execute('''CREATE TABLE stocks
         (date text, trans text, symbol text, qty real, price real)''')

 # Insert a row of data
 c.execute("INSERT INTO stocks VALUES ('2006-01-05','BUY','RHAT',100,35.14)")

 # Save (commit) the changes
 conn.commit()

 # We can also close the connection if we are done with it.
 # Just be sure any changes have been committed or they will be lost.
 conn.close()
```